# Cast one of the operands of multiplication operation to a long?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am multiplying two numbers which is int and storing in long. But it displays error as ,
Cast one of the operands of this multiplication operation to a long. How to solve this?

```
 private int milisecPerSecond = 1000;

/**
 * The update interval in seconds.
 */
// Update frequency in seconds
private int updateIntervalInSec = 5;
 /**
 * The update interval.
 */
// Update frequency in milliseconds
private long updateInterval = milisecPerSecond * updateIntervalInSec;
```

Comment: I don't see how this code results in an error. The int will widen to a long.

Comment: it's code cleaning.. sonarqube issue

Comment: That would have been very relevant to mention in your question, including the entire and exact sonarqube message.

Comment: Exactly. @MarkRotteveel is correct. You should mention what 'it' is that gives this error. Also why you're storing such a relatively small number as 5,000 into a long in the first place. And why the comments say 'update frequency' when they are intervals, not frequencies.

Comment: NB you don't need a variable for milliseconds per second. It isn't going to change. Just use 1000. And all these variables should be final.

Comment: I don't think storing the 1000 in some sort of variable is bad, but it really should be something constant / final, and probably static. The last variable should then be called updateIntervalInMillisec (to stay with your naming convention of the other) - which clearly communicates what it is about. And remove those contradicting comments.

Comment: You may want to _read_ the rule description :  https://nemo.sonarqube.org/coding_rules#rule_key=squid%3AS2184 and please mention if something is not clear.

Comment: What about using [TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis( intervInSecs )](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/TimeUnit.html#toMillis(long)) ?

Answer (score 10):

First, this will not result in a compiler error. It's the usual case to multiply to int numbers and store the result in an int.

A signed int if 32 bit wide can take numbers up to approx. 2 billion. If your code does what it says, this will make an update interval of 2 million seconds, or 23 days.

If you really want to force a long-based calculation, just cast one of its factors:

```
long updateInterval = millisecsPerSecond * (long) updateIntervalInSec;
```

The second factor will get converted automatically then.

Keep in mind that only casting the result will not be enough:

```
private long updateInterval = (long) (milisecPerSecond * updateIntervalInSec);
// THIS WON'T DO AS EXPECTED
```

as it will do the problematic calculation on int and just cast the then maybe wrong result into a long.

Casting is something that's described on the first three pages of every book on Java. If you're serious enough about code quality to run code quality tools, then have someone with knowledge of the language you use sit beside you. A trained pair of fresh eyes for a code review is such a great resource.