# How to solve for Sonarqube issue "Cast one of the operands of this subtraction operation to a 'long'."?

Tags: java, sonarqube

We have an old back-end services that computes for password-changing reminder.

```
 import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

 int daysBeforePasswordExpires = 60;
 Integer daysBeforeReminder = 30;
 long daysLeftToRemind = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(daysBeforeReminder  - daysLeftToRemind );
```

This code actually works but I need to clean an issue found by Sonarqube

```
  Cast one of the operands of this subtraction operation to a "long".
```

Which points to `long daysLeftToRemind = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(daysBeforeReminder  - daysLeftToRemind );`

I've made the following changes `long daysLeftToRemind = TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(daysBeforeReminder  - (long) daysLeftToRemind );` and the Sonarqube issue goes away.

But I'm worried that it could affect how days remaining before reminding is calculated with my changes.

How to solve Sonarqube issue with result of Cast one of the operands of this subtraction operation to a "long"?

Comment: Why are you using a boxed `Integer` here?

Comment: As I said in the first sentence, it's an old back-end services which I didn't implement. It has been always working ever since. I just want to fix the Sonarqube issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cast one of the operands of multiplication operation to a long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38138461/cast-one-of-the-operands-of-multiplication-operation-to-a-long)

Comment: The cast either [A] does nothing, or [B] fixes a bug. There is no point running sonarqube on a codebase if you're afraid of analysing or touching _anything_.

Comment: As @rzwitserloot says, there is no value for either of your operands where your change produces incorrect behaviour. It could *change* behaviour, if, for example, `daysBeforeReminder` is `Integer.MAXVALUE` and `daysLeftToRemind` is negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two points to consider:

1. Integer subtraction is prone to integer overflow / integer underflow. The classical examples are `Integer.MAX_VALUE - -1` and `Integer.MIN_VALUE - 1`.

   Since `TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis()` expects a `long` as argument you can avoid the overflow / underflow by casting one of the operands to `long`.
2. Your business case: your variable names start with `days` which let me believe that they represent some time span measured in days.

   For most practical purposes we might assume that these time spans have a limited range (1000 years are about 365_250 days - I don't think that your time spans exceed that amount of days).

   With such a limited range of values there is no possibility of integer overflow / underflow.

When you only look at the first point then SonarQube is right: you should cast one of your operands to `long`

When you look at the second point too then you may realise that a change might not be necessary (because in your business case an overflow or underflow cannot occur) but introducing the cast will do no harm.

Then the question is more: should you tell SonarQube to ignore this problem? Or do you follow the advice and cast an operand to long?

My suggestion would be to cast one operand to long. The other option (let SonarQube ignore this problem) has the disadvantage that someone might use this code fragment as model for some other code fragment where the possibility of integer overflow / underflow is real.